# Magento CE custom theme files

Tags: css, magento, theming

I am trying to make my own custom magento (1.7) theme, I was using a tutorial that made me add these file structures;

> app > design > frontend > default > 'themename'

And then in that themename map I needed to make;

> default > layout
>
> default > template

And then in skin;

> skin > frontend > default > 'themename'

And then in that themename map I needed to make;

> default > css
>
> default > js
>
> default > images

And so I did. I tried adding a style.css file to that map, as the tutorial said, but nothing happened.. The css said that the bg would be pink, but it isn't. I looked at other tutorials and they were all talking about different kind of file structures. I'm a bit lost now. Where do I need to put my files?

Also, how do I select my theme? I went to System > Configuration > Design in the admin panel, and added the name of my theme in the package bar but then it says no such thing exist...

I'm a bit lost and I'm hoping someone can help. By the way, I disabled caches and I'm not misspelling my theme name or using weird chars, just lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

And your layout and template folders need to be created as

> 'themename'>layout
>
> 'themename'>template
>
> eg:app/design/frontend/default/'themename'/layout
>
> and app/design/frontend/default/'themename'/template

Same goes for the Skin mapping.

Also in magento admin configuration

In Design tab you need to enter the **package** name as `default` as per your config

and in the **themes** in template, layout and skin(Images/CSS) you need to put your `'themename'`.